# "Submit" Form and Direct to Javascript Generated URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a login form that, when completed, sends users to a page with a JavaScript generated URL (allowing me to pass a JavaScript variable to my PHP script using $_GET).  However, in order to do that, the Login button is currently 'type="button"'.  While everything works, it means that users cannot login by hitting Enter; they must actually click the Login button.  Is there a way I can "Submit" the form, while still having it point to the JavaScript generated URL?

This seems like a pretty basic concept, which tells me I might be approaching it the wrong way to begin with.  Any guidance is appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form name="login">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_id"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function check(form) {
    var userCredentials = [["jsmith", "smithpassword", "John Smith"], ["jdoe", "doepassword", "Jane Doe"]];
    var credCheck = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < userCredentials.length; i++) {
        if (userCredentials[i][0] == form.user_id.value) {
            credCheck += 1;
            var displayName = userCredentials[i][2];
            if (userCredentials[i][1] == form.pswrd.value) {
                window.open("home.php?display_name=" + displayName, "_self");
            } else {
                alert('The username and password do not match.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (credCheck == 0) {
        alert('The username entered is not valid.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: put an other name instead of `_self` and set it for `target` for `form`, and then submit the form

Comment: @EL How do you then open the new page in the same window?

Comment: I think, by assigning it once for both form.target and window. Oh, I forgotten. Define a `var` name for window. Just like `var W = window.open(.....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of opening php page via javascript, you need to change the form `action` dynamically to point to your generated url.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="login">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_id"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:** (line 9 & 10 changed)

```
function check(form) {
    var userCredentials = [["jsmith", "smithpassword", "John Smith"], ["jdoe", "doepassword", "Jane Doe"]];
    var credCheck = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < userCredentials.length; i++) {
        if (userCredentials[i][0] == form.user_id.value) {
            credCheck += 1;
            var displayName = userCredentials[i][2];
            if (userCredentials[i][1] == form.pswrd.value) {
                form.action = "home.php?display_name=" + displayName;
                return true;
            } else {
                alert('The username and password do not match.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (credCheck == 0) {
        alert('The username entered is not valid.');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, I can get this to partially work.  When made those changes, I was able to get the form "Submit" as I wanted and go to 'home.php'.  However, the rest of the URL is '?user_id=jsmith&pswrd=smithpassword', instead of '?display_name=JohnSmith'.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @jackel414 add `method="post"` to the `form` tag in your html

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<form name="login" onsubmit="check(this)">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_id"/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That was one of the solutions I tried.  Can't get it to do anything but refresh the page.